# Strings.resx Localizations not Installing in .Net Program

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, localization, .net-3.5

I have a .Net application.  It has a Strings.resx file, along with Strings.es.resx, and many more localizations.

Everything works fine in Visual Studio, if I am using debug or release mode.

But, when I build my install package, and install the software, it's as if the translations are missing.  When I change the programs language from Dutch to Spanish to English, only the default strings are used.

This isn't a problem with having to restart the program.  I save the users expected language.  I then set it without exceptions.

It seems the translations are missing from my install package.  Why?

Comment: There's a pretty heavy Doh! angle here.  Did you actually add those satellite assemblies to your Setup project?  No, it isn't automatic.

Comment: I haven't added them to the setup project.  It seems like Strings.resx is working, but not Strings.es.resx, etc.  I only added the "project output."  How would I add those strings files to a standard Windows deployment project?  For future reference, would it be different if I was doing a clickonce distribution?

Comment: If I add them, do I just put the in the same place as the exe file?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it.  You can add localized resources the same way that you add the primary output.  I think I'm good now.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deployment project had the project output, but that did not include the string files.  I had to manually add the localized resources to the deployment project, by way of Add->Project Output->Localized Resources.

Comment: Hey, Can I change that string value in resource file after installing software?

Comment: I suspect not easily... I think they are compiled into some bite code.  But, I don't know for sure.